# Is there any process to reduce the count "Defer unused CSS" for a wrdpress website

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to find unused CSS in a wordpress website? I'm trying to clean up a project. I just inherited.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a performance audit with Chrome's built in audit or get the Lighthouse extension.  It will tell you which files contain unused CSS.  See if you need the plugin stylesheet.  If you don't, you can `wp_dequeue_style()` the entire sheet.

If you want a more indepth look at say your own stylesheet, Google Dev Tools also has a tool called `Coverage` that tells you how much of a style or script is used.

> To open the DevTools Command Menu, press Cmd+Shift+P (Mac) or Ctrl+Shift+P (Windows, Linux).

To read more about it, go to their [official release notes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes).

The inspector will show you every style or function not in use. If they are post type specific, you can break them into separate files and enqueue them based on post type by doing a check in your functions.php.